# VBA Type Mismatch (Run time error 13) when pasting a whole row of data

Tags: vba, excel

I'm currently facing issues and I've no idea why..

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Intersect(Target, Columns("B:B")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub

If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
    Range(Range("A" & Target.Row), Range("I" & Target.Row)).Copy _
    Sheets("UpdateModify Forms").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Range(Range("AC" & Target.Row), Range("AU" & Target.Row)).Copy _
    Sheets("UpdateModify Forms").Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

ElseIf Target.Value = "No" Then
    Range(Range("A" & Target.Row), Range("AB" & Target.Row)).Copy _
    Sheets("Development Forms").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
    Range(Range("AW" & Target.Row), Range("AY" & Target.Row)).Copy _
    Sheets("Development Forms").Range("AC" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)

End If
End Sub
```

The Error is pointing on

```
If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
```

**How it should work:**

when i paste a row filled with data, by right it should check for the criteria wheter it's Yes or No, and sorting it to their distinctive sheet.

**BUT**

It appeared the run time error 13 for some reason.. i only know how to bypass it which is to manually type in data and avoid the column where it will trigger the validation first and key in other datas first and finally that validation column.

**One more question:**

Is there anyway to print the whole thing without me inputting the validation column LAST? Because i tried to key the validation column first and when i continue filling up the row beside it, it dont show on the next sheet, only displaying "Yes" or "No" Which is the Column B

Any help would be appreciated, thanks for the time!

Comment: Add watch on Target.Value and see what its type is.

Comment: Try `Columns(2)` or `Columns("B")`

Comment: Tried using 'If Intersect(Target, Columns(2)) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub' and 'If Intersect(Target, Columns("B")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub' but still get the same error and same yellow highlighted on the 'If Target.Value = "Yes" Then'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you update a whole row, `Target` will be a whole row.  You can't test whether an entire row is "Yes" - you need to look at a single cell.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Columns("B")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In Intersect(Target, Columns("B:B")).Cells
        If cel.Value = "Yes" Then
            Range(Range("A" & cel.Row), Range("I" & cel.Row)).Copy _
                     Sheets("UpdateModify Forms").Range("A" & Sheets("UpdateModify Forms").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Range(Range("AC" & cel.Row), Range("AU" & cel.Row)).Copy _
                     Sheets("UpdateModify Forms").Range("J" & Sheets("UpdateModify Forms").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)    
        ElseIf cel.Value = "No" Then
            Range(Range("A" & cel.Row), Range("AB" & cel.Row)).Copy _
                     Sheets("Development Forms").Range("A" & Sheets("Development Forms").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)
            Range(Range("AW" & cel.Row), Range("AY" & cel.Row)).Copy _
                     Sheets("Development Forms").Range("AC" & Sheets("Development Forms").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0)    
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

As for the other question as to whether there is a way to have this process only after the whole row has been filled in, I would suggest you have a button and have the user click the button when they finish - thus avoiding a `Worksheet_Change` event.  Or at least make the very last column be the one to trigger the `Change`.

---

In response to comment requesting values:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Intersect(Target, Columns("B:B")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    Dim cel As Range
    For Each cel In Intersect(Target, Columns("B:B")).Cells
        If cel.Value = "Yes" Then
            With Sheets("UpdateModify Forms")
                With .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
                    .Range("A1:I1").Value = Rows(cel.Row).Range("A1:I1").Value
                'I commented out the next two lines because I assume the
                'last row in column A should be the same as the last row
                'in column J - uncomment them if that is not the case.
                'End With
                'With .Range("J" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
                    .Range("J1:AB1").Value = Rows(cel.Row).Range("AC1:AU1").Value
                End With
            End With
        ElseIf cel.Value = "No" Then
            With Sheets("Development Forms")
                With .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
                    .Range("A1:AB1").Value = Rows(cel.Row).Range("A1:AB1").Value
                'End With
                'With .Range("AC" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).EntireRow
                    .Range("AC1:AE1").Value = Rows(cel.Row).Range("AW1:AY1").Value
                End With
            End With
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Omg it works! Thanks a lot! but there is a minor change to be done, for the 'If Intersect(Target, Columns("B:B")) Is Nothing Then Exit Sub', the Columns("B:B") changed to Columns("B")

Comment: @user7809596 - Oops - I hadn't noticed that the first statement was a single-line `If` - have edited the answer accordingly.  Note: There is no difference between `Columns("B:B")` and `Columns("B")` and `Columns(2)` - they all mean the same thing.

Comment: @user7809596 I approved your edit (which clobbered mine where I was fixing the mistake due to the single-line `If`) and then "improved" it back to how it was - I didn't want you to get a "reject" recorded against your name - because you submitted the edit before I mentioned that it was no different to what I had.

Comment: No worries ! I'm still new to this hahaha, thanks a lot!

Comment: By the way, how am i able to paste the Formula's value instead of bring it over the Whole formula into the cell? @YowE3K

Comment: oh i had found a solution already, sorry for the trouble! heh

Comment: @user7809596 - I updated the answer to show how to copy the values anyway.  (See how it compares to the solution you found :D )

Comment: OMG you somehow read my mind HAHAHA that was exactly what i wanted to find.. the way i tried copy and pasting is making the whole excel lag x( thanks a bunch!!

If let's say i wanted to instead of shifting it to a new worksheet, to shift it to a new workbook located at my desktop, is there a way? or it's impossible to do that? >:

Comment: @user7809596 - That's not hard (it's just qualifying the `Worksheets` references with the appropriate `Workbooks` reference) - but it is now getting beyond the scope of this question.  Raise a new question if you can't find a way to do it be searching for things like "opening another workbook" and "copying data between two workbooks".

Answer (score 0):

when multiple cells is selected, it would be error when you trying to use `target.value`. Try use `target.values` when `selection.cells.count > 1`.

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest passing the intersection into a variable,

```
Dim MyTarget as range
Set MyTarget = Intersect(Target, Columns("B:B"))
```

Next check if there is an intersection by,

```
If MyTarget Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
```

You can now loop through that variable using

```
Dim EachCell as Range
For Each EachCell in MyTarget
'do your thing here
Next
```

-Romcel